# Which scopes and APIs to use with Microsoft Live OAuth?

Tags: oauth-2.0, microsoft-graph-api

I've been trying to include Microsoft OAuth authentication in my web app using the following documentations :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-v2-protocols-oauth-code

And:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh243647.aspx

My question is this : should I use `login.live.com` or `login.microsoftonline.com`, and which scope should I use to get access to the user's profile (mail address, first name, last name) ?

A scope that I would like to use is `wl.basic` which is described over there : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/hh243646.aspx

However, when I try using this scope with any of `login.microsoftonline.com` or `login.live.com`, I get an error response telling me that the scope isn't recognized.

The only scope I've been able to use is `https://graph.microsoft.com/mail.read`. Any other scope either isn't recognized, or is completely ignored by the access token request (I've also tried the following scopes: openid, mail, profile, offline_access).